# Java startup with URL parameters

Tags: java, url, parameters

I want to start my java application from within another program using a startup path. In this path I want to pass on a couple of parameters for the java application

Example: C:/Users/TestApp.jar/-username -password (?)

In java:

```
public class TestApp_Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String username = parameter from the url(?)
        String password = parameter from the url(?)

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CB_View mainView = new CB_View(username, password);
                mainView.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Would be very thankful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What are the problems that you are currently facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command line arguments. The parameter to your main method is actually the array of your command line arguments. So accessing args[0] gives the first argument, accessing args[2] is the third and so on.

For example if you execute your application with:

```
java TestApp user pass123
```

You can access parameters in code with:

```
String username = args[0]; //value: user
String password = args[1]; //value: pass123
```

You can refer to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for more info.